# Jquery function as object

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have created a javascript function like the following:

```
function highlight_input() {
  $("input").css("background", "yellow");
}

$("#input1").highlight_input();
$("#input2").highlight_input();
```

Now I want to highlight the two input types when need! but both should not be highlighted at a time!

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do more clearly. What do you mean "when you need"?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a [basic plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) by adding function to `jQuery.fn`(extending jQuery prototype), where `this` refers to the jQuery object inside the function.

```js
jQuery.fn.highlight_input = function() {
  // here this refers to the jQuery object , so 
  // you can apply jQuery methods without wrapping
  this.css("background", "yellow");
  // return the object reference to keep chaining
  return this;
}

$("#input1").highlight_input();
$("#input2").highlight_input();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<input>
```

---

Even you can pass the color as an argument in case you want to apply custom color in some case.

```js
jQuery.fn.highlight_input = function(color) {
  // if argument is undefined use the default value
  // although you can return in the same line since 
  // css method returns the object reference
  return this.css("background", color || "yellow");
}

$("#input1").highlight_input();
// passing color as argument
$("#input2").highlight_input("red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1">
<input id="input2">
<input>
```

Comment: You are on the right path but not the right way. read this and adapt your answer. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Comment: Also, keep in mind that doing a jq selector may return you and array of objects.

Comment: @DincaAdrian : extend is using to add multiple properties.... which provides the same behaviour

Comment: @DincaAdrian : jQuery selector returns an array like object and not an array.... by index we can retrieve DOM object... to get jQuery object we can use `eq()` method.....

Answer (score 0):

jQuery plugins will do the job

```
$.fn.highlight_input = function(){
  return this.css({background:"yellow"});
}
```

you can additionally pass a desired color argument (that will fallback to yellow

```
$.fn.highlight_input = function(color) {
  return this.css({background: color||"yellow"});
}
```

use like

```
$("selector").highlight_input("#f80");
```